# Installing Windows XP from the Hard Drive

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installation

I have an old pc that does not support Windows XP installation using flash drive, the only way to get it done is to boot it from its hard drive(since I dont have a CD/DVD Drive). Can you give a step by step procedure on how to install Windows XP from the hard drive?

Comment: Were you not able to find this out using a search engine?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a second PC that supports that type of HDD, here's what you need to do:

1. Attach HDD to have XP on it to the PC supporting a CD, and burn XP to CD.
2. **IMPORTANT:** Detach ALL other drives, apart from the CD drive and the HDD to have XP.
3. Boot the installer
4. Install XP up to where it wants to reboot
5. At the POST prompt, shut the PC down, and attach the original drives
6. Attach the XP drive to the PC that needs XP
7. Boot the XP PC and let it install XP
8. Enjoy

Hope this helps

Comment: Im sorry to tell you, I dont have a second PC. Is there any software that will allow you not to use a  second pc?

Comment: unfortunately not, unless you can boot to a CD, you're left without many options

Comment: how about copying OS from one computer to my dead pc? Is it possible?

Comment: nope, again, not without USB or CD boot support

Comment: I do have a USB. How?

Comment: this is what you said: "...does not support Windows XP installation using flash drive..." CAN the PC boot USB drives?

Comment: Hi, once again, I have a laptop, is it possible now?

Comment: is the dead PC a laptop or desktop?

Comment: The dead PC is a desktop but I have a laptop here.

Comment: Then no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least another computer like your laptop.

1. Detach your hard drive.
2. Connect it to a different computer using a hard drive enclosure. You can find these on Amazon for different sized hard drives. If it is a desktop hard drive, it will also need external power supply.
3. Install Windows XP to that hard drive. You have two options here.

   - Option 1: On your other computer, detach its original hard drive or disable it in its BIOS. Then boot with whatever boot media that is supported, be it CD or flash, and install to your USB hard drive.

     - Caveat 1: This still require you to have a boot media.
     - Caveat 2: If Windows XP does not have driver for your USB controller, you won't see the hard drive so it won't work.
   - Option 2: On your other computer, install VMware Workstation Player (freeware). Create a virtual machine and attach your USB hard drive as whole-disk physical drive to that VM, and attach the Windows XP ISO file to a virtual optical drive on that VM. Then boot the VM and install as if you are installing from a optical drive.
4. Put the hard drive back to your original machine.

---

Based on the above options, I think the VMware option is better and could be more stable. Only that you need to make sure to attach the whole-disk, instead of just some partitions. This is because we need to modify the partition table on the hard drive.

Documents: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/17.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-2A1F74A4-A5F3-4090-9A45-396D6D407CE5.html